# Outlook - convert straight quotes to curly quotes

Tags: microsoft-outlook, smart-quotes

I often write things in Notepad, with straight quotes.
When I copy and paste them into Outlook, I have to laboriously go through and re-type them (using Outlook's smart quotes).

I'd love a way to select all the text in Outlook, and convert the quotes/apostrophes automatically - is there a way?

Comment: You could type in Word instead, or write VBA that replaces the quotes for you in Outlook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to accomplish:

- Paste your text into Outlook.
- Highlight one of the double straight quotes and copy.
- Do a find and replace.
- Find what:  paste the double straight quotes.
- Replace with:  Type a double quote.
- Replace All.